# Asynchronously updating multiple row updates 1/4 of rows instantly and then waits

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous

I have a code to asynchronously update multiple rows in SQL Server's table. I tested it on updating 540 rows and 144 rows are updated in the table instanly, then it waits for about 5 minutes and then the rest is updated. At least this is how it looks when I check for updated rows with SELECT.. I'm wondering why is that.

The whole thing is triggered by button's click:

```
DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show($"Znaleziono {num} pasujących maszyn. Czy chcesz zaktualizować priorytet maszyny danymi z pliku?", "Potwierdź", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if(res == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                await UpdatePriority();
                MessageBox.Show("Updated!");
```

Here's UpdatePriority method that asynchronously call place.Edit() method for all places in the list of items:

```
public async Task<string> UpdatePriority()
        {
            List<Task<string>> UpdateTasks = new List<Task<string>>();

            try
            {
                foreach (Place p in Items.Where(i => i.IsUpdated==true))
                {
                    UpdateTasks.Add(Task.Run(()=> p.Edit()));
                }

                string response = "OK";

                IEnumerable<string> res = await Task.WhenAll<string>(UpdateTasks);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return "Nie udało się zaktualizować danych żadnego zasobu..";
        }
```

And here is Edit() method of place object. It basically updates place data in SQL server table:

```
public async Task<string> Edit()
        {
            string iSql = @"UPDATE JDE_Places
                            SET Priority=@Priority
                            WHERE PlaceId=@PlaceId";
            string msg = "OK";


            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(iSql, Settings.conn))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlaceId", PlaceId);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Priority", Priority);

                int result = -1;

                try
                {
                    result = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    IsUpdated = false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    msg = $"Wystąpił błąd przy edycji zasobu {Name}. Opis błędu: {ex.Message}";
                }

            }
            return msg;
        }
```

And here's Settings conn property that serves as reusable connection object:

```
public static class Settings
    {
        private static SqlConnection _conn { get; set; }
        public static SqlConnection conn
        {
            get
            {
                if (_conn == null)
                {
                    _conn = new SqlConnection(Static.Secrets.ConnectionString);
                }
                if (_conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed || _conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        _conn.Open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Nie udało się nawiązać połączenia z bazą danych.. " + ex.Message);
                    }

                }
                return _conn;
            }
        }
    }
```

I realize it's probably better to keep the connection within using statement (instead of reusing it), but when I added it to place.Edit() method it worked even slower (and unreliably).

UPDATE: I ran few tests more and the time they took to add 540 rows varied from 15 seconds to 400 seconds.. Then I just changed `result = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` to `result = command.ExecuteNonQuery()` in Edit() of place object, ran few tests more, and all finished under 10 seconds! I don't know why async version of ExecuteNonQuery() was so much worse than non-async one, though. Single Edit() method was taking around 0,1 sec with ExecuteNonQuery() and 1 - 400 seconds with ExecuteNonQueryAsync(). Here are logs: [ExecuteNonQuery()](https://www.szybkiplik.pl/eo2v5N9vwd) [ExecuteNonQueryAsync()](https://www.szybkiplik.pl/4it3Jo3NgA)

Comment: Could you try logging the completion of each `Edit` task, so that you have a better view of what's going on?

Comment: There are no locks around your static `_conn` variable. Likely it's a concurrency issue that's instantiating multiple SqlConnection instances until it fills up the connection pool.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias good idea, I'll put some nLog in place and post its findings.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I agree it may be the case here. I'm wondering, though, why does it take that much time. I checked in Sql Server's activity monitor but it show no peaks/bottlenecks during running of the code. Now, even though I used async code, the execution is much slower than same code running synchronously.. Maybe I should adjust timeout or some other property?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is your `Settings` class. You're essentially trying to use the same `SqlConnection` object in multiple `Sqlcommand`s. `SqlConnection` is not threadsafe when used like this. You end up with multiple commands because your code is non-blocking and async. That is what is causing your code the "wait" (or deadlock). This is why when you run it sync (without the `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`, etc.) it works correctly.

You don't need this object at all anyway. [ADO.Net handles connection pooling for you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling?redirectedfrom=MSDN), so there is no advantage in re-using the same `SqlConnection`. Just create a new one for each `SqlCommand`:

```cs
public async Task<string> Edit()
{


       using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...))
       using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(iSql, conn))
       {
       ...
       }
   }
```

and you should find that your "wait" goes away.